# Tree view node add returning null

Tags: c#

```
   string partName = "";
            string confName = "";
            string workName = "";
            foreach (string[] e in instance.aWkshpJag)
            {
                foreach (string[] ex in instance.aPartJag)
                {
                    if (e[0] == ex[0])
                    {
                        partName = ex[1] + " " + ex[2];
                        confName = ex[4];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                foreach (string[] exr in instance.aWorkJag)
                {
                    if (e[1] == exr[0])
                    {
                        workName = exr[2];
                    }
                }
                treeViewWkshp.BeginUpdate();
                treeViewWkshp.Nodes[confName].Nodes[workName].Nodes.Add(partName);
                treeViewWkshp.EndUpdate();

            }
```

This is throwing a null exception, even though all variables have values. Reasons why this may be?

-EDIT- Added more of the code block.

Null exception is thrown at

```
treeViewWkshp.Nodes[confName].Nodes[workName].Nodes.Add(partName);

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=FBLA_App
```

Comment: need more detail. null exception where? show the actual error message

Comment: Provide exception stack trace

Comment: What is the type of `treeViewWkshp`? Is this a WPF or WinForms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-write the offending line like this, you will still get the same `NullReferenceException`, but it will be on a line that contains only one null reference possibility.

```
var confNode = treeViewWkshp.Nodes[confName];
var workNode = confNode.Nodes[workName];
var workNodeChildren = workNode.Nodes
workNodeChildren.Add(partName);
```

Comment: Workname has a value but var workNodeChildren = workNode.Nodes; returns null. What does this mean?

Comment: If `workNode.Nodes` returns null, then this suggests that there `workNode` has no child nodes...

Comment: I already have a parent node and achild node under it. How would i add yet another node to the child node

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not all variables have values. Try splitting your line of code so that one node at a time is declared and accessed.